# How to use awk to get Maximum and Average of scores of all column A pairs with column B?

Tags: linux, awk

Say I have this file1.csv consists of column A and column A_score looks like this:

```
fefa68e,312
wernjnn,432
ew443fs,300
```

and file2.csv consists of pairs of column B and column A looks like this:

```
dfaefew,fefa68e
dfaefew,wernjnn
vzcxvvz,ew443fs
ewrwefd,wernjnn
ewrwefd,ew443fs
```

How can I get a file3.csv to get the maximum of scores of all column A pairs with column B looks like this:

```
dfaefew,432
vzcxvvz,300
ewrwefd,432
```

and a file4.csv to get the average of scores of all column A pairs with column B looks like this:

```
dfaefew,372
vzcxvvz,300
ewrwefd,366
```

Can awk or anything else do the work? I am using ubuntu.

Thx ahead!

Update:

What if the file2.csv looks like this:

```
dfaefew,fefa68e,1
dfaefew,wernjnn,1
vzcxvvz,ew443fs,1
ewrwefd,wernjnn,0
ewrwefd,ew443fs,0
```

The third column could be 1 or 0 and 1 and it is the same for the same column 1 value(dfaefew, vzcxvvz etc) and I want to keep the third column and get output like this:

```
dfaefew,432,1
vzcxvvz,300,1
ewrwefd,432,0

dfaefew,372,1
vzcxvvz,300,1
ewrwefd,366,0
```

Comment: Your example isn't complete. Where do the other numbers come from?

Comment: the average or maximum of A_scores of all column A pairs with column B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it in `awk`:

#### Contents of `script.awk`:

```
# Set the input and output field separators to ","
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }   

# Processing first file
# Load the first file in hash keyed at column1 having value of column2
NR==FNR { value[$1] = $2; next }   

# Processing second file
# Keep a counter of column1 and add values for column2
{ count[$1]++; values[$1]+=value[$2] }   

# Find the max for each entry of column1
{ entry[$1] = (($1 in entry) && entry[$1]>value[$2] ? entry[$1] : value[$2]) } 

# In the END block traverse through array and print desired output.
END {
     for (max in entry) print (max, entry[max]) > "file3.csv";
     for (key in entry) print (key, values[key]/count[key]) > "file4.csv";
}
```

#### Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk file1.csv file2.csv
```

#### Output:

```
$ cat file3.csv
vzcxvvz,300
ewrwefd,432
dfaefew,432
```

```
$ cat file4.csv
vzcxvvz,300
ewrwefd,366
dfaefew,372
```

Comment: This is nitpicky to point out, but if for some reason all the scores are negative for a given entry then I think the max will end up being 0. If that's a possibility, better to check first `if ($1 in entry)` before checking `entry[$1] > value[$2]`.

Comment: @jas Good point! Updated the solution to handle it. Thank you!

Comment: thank you so much!!! I add a update question in the original question could you help me with that?

Comment: @user3692521 Quick way to do it is to add another array to the line `{ count[$1]++; values[$1]+=value[$2]; last[$1]=$NF }` and then add a reference to it in the `END` block by saying `print (max, entry[max], last[max])` and `print (key, values[key]/count[key], last[key])`.